# R: Finding a mean for columns selected by different column

Tags: r, statistics

Homework.

I have a data frame of people in rows with their age, sex and whether they died during an accident. Example:

```
Age    Sex    Survival
45     male   1
23     female 1
34     male   0
65     female 1
```

where the value in "Survival" detonates if the person survived or not. 1 is survivor, 0 is dead.

I want to implement a function that takes age as an argument and returns the probability of survival.

I have tried this code, but it is not working for me:

```
fun <- function(x) mean(subset(data_with_only_males, Age = x))
```

Comment: Yo probably need a logistic regression model to calculate such probabilities

Comment: Do you have enough data points as to calculate proportion survival for each age?

Comment: I should have sufficient data points. I will try to find a logistic regression model for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the `==` operator (which tests for equality) in the argument `Age == x`.  Also `subset()` returns a data.frame when it's passed a data.frame, so you need to use the `$` operator to select the survival variable from the data.frame before taking the mean.

```
fun <- function(x) 
    mean(subset(data_with_only_males, Age == x)$Survival)
```